# How to make docker-compose load the context from GIT to a specific directory?

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
web:
   build:
       context: git@git.example.com:/abc/abc-backend
   volumes:
       - ./.data/app:/app
```

The git repository has a Dockerfile in it such as this one:

```
FROM python:3.5
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN ./manage.py runserver
```

requirements.txt is inside the git repository. When I do `docker-compose build`, it gives me error:

> Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'

My understanding is that, docker-compose clones the repository to a directory that I don't know. Is there a way I can change where docker-compose clones the directory? I want the directory to be cloned to `/app`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Dockerfile never copies any files into the image.  You need to add a `COPY . /app/` instruction before the `RUN pip ...` instruction, just as if you were building from a local context instead of a Git repository.

Comment: Also, the last line from your Dockerfile seems to be the command to start your application. If so, it should actually be a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`, like this: `CMD ["./manage.py", "runserver"]`